# How to add link in jquery DataTables column?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have succeeded adding the link in the column but I can't seem to add the url/path in the href attribute. How can I add the path/url and the title in the function below so that the link will be functional? In other words, how can I pass two different columns/fields to the function below?

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "bProcessing":true,
                        "aaData":results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows,
                        "aoColumns":[
                        {
                            "mData":"Title",
                            "mPath":"Path",
                        "render": function ( mData,type, full, meta ) {
                              return '<a href="'+mPath+'">' + mData+'</a>';                             
                            }
                        },
                        {"mData":"Path"}
                        ]
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution is to add the Path column to the table and then read the data for each row from this column and add the link to the other column.like this:

```
var oTable = $('#articlesOverview').DataTable({
                            "iDisplayLength": 25,
                            "bDestroy": true,
                            "bProcessing":true,
                            "aaData":results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows,
                            "aoColumns":[
                            {
                                "mData":"Title",
                                "render": function ( mData, type,row, meta ) {
                                  return '<a href="' + removeLastSlash(row.Path) + '">' + mData+'</a>';                             
                                }
                            },
                            {"mData":"Path",
                            "visible": false}
                            ]
                        });
```

For now it is OK, but I was expecting a much more elegant way than this.
If someone has got a better way without creating a second column that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the beginning and closing `"` in your return statement. Example:

```
return '<a href=\"'+mPath+'\">' + mData+'</a>';
```

Comment: No it does not work. results.m_`value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows`, has got a property called Path and I would like to use this in my hyperlink. How can I access that?

Answer (score 0):

From your answer to your question it looks like "Path" is a member of your ResultRows objects. Can you access it directly from the Title column like so:

```
var oTable = $('#articlesOverview').DataTable({
               "iDisplayLength": 25,
               "bDestroy": true,
               "bProcessing":true,
               "aaData":results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows,
               "aoColumns":[
                 {
                   "mData":"Title",
                   "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                     return '<a href="' + full.Path + '">'+data+'</a>';
                   }
                 }
               ]
             });
```

If the link in the anchor's href is non-functional, I would look for a character conflict within the path.